# Add badges for handling topic requests

Tags: feature-request, documentation, badge-request, documentation-topics

There's one thing that stands out about Documentation: there's just *so many* topic requests that haven't been handled! [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) has nearly 100, [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) has over 150, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) has 26, etc.

What can we do about this? <s>Actually handle topic requests</s> Add badges for handling topic requests! I propose the following 3 badges to be added:

- [bronze] Niche: handle first topic request with at least one example having a positive score
- [silver] Researcher: handle 5 topic requests with at least one example having a positive score
- [gold] Database: handle 10 topic requests with at least one example having a positive score

Oh yeah, that's another thing: at present, there are no gold badges for docs. We should add some.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering the quality of such requests (I saw an iOS topic request for *Metal*, which is both far too big to be a topic and not limited to iOS), encouraging Robo-topic-creation will "help" only by making Docs.SO even less useful than it already is.

Comment: +1 for the argument, but 1) even the gold badge I'm proposing only requires 10 handled, and 2) that's why I added the requirement of _must have at least one example with a positive score_.

Comment: @SomePerson: If you post enough examples/topics, you will eventually get an upvote from someone.